# OBSOLETE - Search Stack Exchange Network of Q&A sites instantly with SEInstant

Tags: app, obsolete, search

> #Obsolete - Site long dead; no source code available. Was written for decommissioned version of the API.

**About**

Stack Exchange search results are now fast, faster, instant! :)
Following on the heels of "Google Instant," which provides search results as you type, here's "Stack Exchange Instant." Stack Exchange Instant Search is a new search enhancement that shows results as you type.
You'll also be shown a range of possible queries, that might be similar to the one you're typing, in grey to refine your options, all before you ever hit the "Search" button.
*A fast Internet connection is however recommended for the 'instant' feeling.*

Please let me know in comments what you think about this app. Don't you think that it is laggy?
Does it has a right to live?
Currently there is an usage limits 100 queries/day, but I hope it is enough for evaluation purposes. I've already requested more.
I've created this web app basically for test  instant search' possibilities. It is a little buggy at the moment, but mostly work. Consider this as rough prototype and not final application.
Inspired by Google Instant, created with Google Web Toolkit, running on Google App Engine, searches on Google. Google pursues me :)

**Technologies**
App is using Google Custom search API behind the scene. After receiving search results from Google engine, app makes request to Stack Exchange API to pull the main questions details. Because of such approach response time is not so instant as it should be for really 'instant' feeling ;-)
Supported sites list: http://seinstant.appspot.com/sites

**Screenshots**
[image]

[image]

**Access**
http://seinstant.appspot.com

**Platform**
Freely available web page

**Contact**
Brought to you by Vladislav Tserman. I'm available at: vladjan (at) gmail.com

**Code**
Written in Java, Google Web Toolkit under Eclipse Helios.
Application uses the Stack Exchange API and is powered by Google App Engine for Java.

**Future**
Application still in beta stage. I hope you're not having any problems, but if you are, please let me know. Leave your feedback and bug reports in comments.
I want to hear from the users and incorporate as much feedback as possible into the extension.
Any suggestions for improvements/features to add?

Comment: dude - this frikkin rocks! very quick and clean.

Comment: **+10000** - just amazing!

Comment: Thanks guys. I released some minor updates: highlighting searched words, some fixes in search box, performance improvements. Should become a little faster now. Enjoy!

Comment: is this app dead? 404

Answer (score 3):

**Suggestions**:

1. allow user to set a cookie for specifying result count up to 100 per page.
2. *more to come*

Answer (score 1):

A little laggy, but still pretty awesome.
Could you remove the results down so the first one isn't hidden by the suggestion box?